# Linux process automatically starts again with new new PID after killing

Tags: node.js, linux, amazon-ec2

I wanna stop Node server on linux but when I try to stop it, It automatically starts with new PID how can I stop this completely. Here you can see I tried to stop Nginx and Node.

[image: Image showing Node process dosen't kill after multiple tries]

How can I check if it is a linux zombie process? If yes then How can I kill it? otherwise

I have tried tried these commands.

```
kill pid
Kill -9 pid
killall node <<command not working
```

Comment: are you using pm2?

Comment: @mahatmanich No. This is just express server no PM2, forever, nodemon, it's just express server.

Comment: are you using the right process? There might be parent process that  does not grep with node, so it respawns only a child process ...

Comment: see 'ps auxf' and no grep

Comment: also try `sudo kill <pid>` or `sudo kill -9 <pid>`

Comment: @mahatmanich nope It's behaving the same, It starts process after killing . same as above screenshot.

Comment: It is hard to tell what is going on in that instance ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was spawn by it's parent process, I search out parent process after killing that this stop as well.